# How does azure cosmosdb change feed internal communication work?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Hi I am wandering how the internal mechanism of subscribing to an azure cosmosdb change feed actually works. Specifically if you are using azure-cosmosdb-js from node. Is there some sort of long polling mechanism that checks a change feed table or are events pushed to the subscriber using web-sockets?

Are there any limits on the number of subscriptions that you can have to any partition keys change feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the change feed as nothing other than an event source that keeps track of document changes.

All the actual change feed consuming logic is abstracted into the SDKs. The server just offers the change feed as something the SDK can consume. That is what the change feed processor libraries are using to operate.

We don't know much about the Change Feed Processor SDKs mainly because they are not open source. (Edit: Thanks to Matias for pointing out that they are actually [open source now](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-dotnet)). However, from extensive personal usage I can tell you the following.

The Change Feed Processor will need a collection to store some documents. Those documents are just checkpoints for the processor to keep track of the consumption. Each main document in those lease collections corresponds to a physical partition. Each physical partition will be polled by the processor in a set interval. you can set that by setting the `FeedPollDelay` setting which "*gets or sets the delay in between polling a partition for new changes on the feed, after all current changes are drained.*".

The library is also capable of spreading the leases if multiple processors are running against a single collection. If a service fails, the running services will pick up the lease. Due to polling and delays you might end up reprocessing already processed documents. You can also choose to set the `CheckpointFrequency` of the change feed processor.

In terms of "subscriptions", you can have as many as you want. Keep in mind however that the change feed processor is writing the lease documents. They are smaller than 1kb so you will be paying the minimum charge of 10 RUs per change. However, if you end up with more than 40 physical partitions you might have to raise the throughput from the minimum 400 RU/s.

Comment: Just to clarify Nick's answer, the Change Feed Processor is open source https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-dotnet :) an overview explanation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor

Comment: Oh wow @MatiasQuaranta that's awesome! Last time I checked I think it was closed. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks NickChapsas, thanks @MatiasQuaranta, so I had a look at the code and correct me if I am wrong, the change feed uses Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client and long polling (sleepTime) to make requests to the partition. So then do you end up paying for just being subscribed to a partition while it polls even if no records have changed? Or Not? If you have partitioned your data by lets say userKey and you create a change feed per user you are effectively long polling every partition?

Comment: The Change Feed Processor does long polling only if your container has not a constant volume of operations. When the feed is read, and changes are sent to your Observer, if the Processor tries to fetch changes and finds nothing, then it will wait for 5 seconds (default, configurable) to do another read. Otherwise if your operations are constant, it's reading and pushing to the Observer continuously. You subscribe to changes to a container, not a particular subset of Partition Key Ranges.